# Convert a byte to char in Swift

Tags: casting, swift, char, byte

I'm using NSInputStream to read msgs.
The read method returns the msg in bytes, same like in Java.
I would like to take the byte and print it as char (e.g. in Java `println((char) 97) // prints "a"`)

How would I do that in Swift?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
let b: UInt8 = 97

print(Character(UnicodeScalar(b)))
```

If you wanted to make this cleaner, you could extend `UInt8` and `Int`:

```
extension UInt8 {
    var char: Character {
        return Character(UnicodeScalar(self))
    }
}

extension Int {
    var char: Character {
        return Character(UnicodeScalar(self))
    }
}

print(b.char)   // prints "a"
print(98.char)  // prints "b"
```

Comment: Hey vacawama, thanks but this looks like a very expensive action.

Comment: True. If you were wanting to just print a few characters it would be fine, but for a large buffer full it would be prohibitively slow.

Comment: WELL, IT"S NOT TRUE.

I have tested this myself, the results are the exact opposite from what we expected.
Your way of converting a byte to a Character is WAY FASTER than with the NSString special constructor.

I have run this code:
`var a :UInt8 = 97
let start = NSDate()
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
//    Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(a)))
    NSString(bytes: &a, length: 1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
let end = NSDate()
println(end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start)) // prints 0.402378976345062`

when I switch the comment, running this in your way, this is the time:
0.00333899259567261

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is as string rather than a character (seems more useful for what you're trying to do? You said you have bytes, but asked about individual characters)?

Anyway you can do this with NSString:

```
var char = 97

let str = NSString(bytes: &char, length: 1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

You said you're using NSInputStream... here's how to put that together:

```
// create a stream to work with
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://abhibeckert.com/"))
let stream = NSInputStream.inputStreamWithData(data)

// read from the stream
var buffer = [UInt8](count:100, repeatedValue: 0)
stream.open()

while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
  stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)

  // get a string for the current section of the buffer
  let str = NSString(bytes: buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```